# Ubuntu boots to black screen with multiboot on Nexus 7

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

-I am using Multirom
-My internal rom is stock 4.2.1
-I also have PA 3.0 installed via multirom
- using Kernel w/ kexec-hardboot patch (stock 4.2)

When I install Ubuntu it will go to the boot screen (where it says 'Ubuntu' with the little loading squares flashing) then it eventually just goes black and doesn't respond. Any ideas on this black screen of death? Let me know if you guys have any info, tried to google around but can't seem to find this specific problem specifically with the nexus 7 install (and on multiboot setup)

Answer (score 0):

I have an image file of ubuntu from February 12th that boots fine on my Nexus 7 using multirom. Only issue I have is graphical bugs during the installation. I had to restart it the first time in order to get the install window to show up as well. If you want, I can try to upload a copy somewhere.

Edit: Here's a link for anyone that wants to try it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mavvaojwdnlahf/raring-preinstalled-desktop-armhf%2Bnexus7.img.gz